# Flink is not adding any data to Elasticsearch but trying with input file as source adding data to ES

Tags: api, elasticsearch, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, data-stream

I'm using the flink data streaming API, but I was able to create and submit a Flink job that would take some JSON input files, aggregate them, and then place the results in Elasticsearch.

But when i use kafka as source , i couldn't output my aggregate to STDOUT or Elasticsearch, and it appears that nothing is occurring there (no data being added). The Flink job manager log appears to be in good shape, based on my review (no errors)

This is my java code

```
package org.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.RuntimeContext;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.TumblingEventTimeWindows;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch.RequestIndexer;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.ElasticsearchSink;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create a StreamExecutionEnvironment
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        // enable event time processing
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

        // create a properties object for the Kafka consumer
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.setProperty("group.id", "testing");

        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setGroupId("testing")
                .setTopics(Collections.singletonList("test"))
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .setProperties(props)
                .build();

        // read the JSON data as a stream of Strings from Kafka
        DataStream<String> inputStream = env.fromSource(kafkaSource,
                WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(),
                "KafkaSource");        


        // parse the JSON payload and extract the required fields
        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Double>> outputStream = inputStream
                // Assign timestamp and watermark
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
                        .<String>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> getTimestampFromJson(event)))
                .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Double>>() {
                    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, Double> map(String value) throws Exception {
                        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(value);
                        String id = root.get("id").asText();
                        double maxspeed = 0.0;
                        if (root.get("messageData").isArray()) {
                            for (JsonNode messageData : root.get("messageData")) {
                                Double Speed = messageData.get("Speed").asDouble();
                                if (Speed != 145.96901) {
                                    maxspeed = max(maxspeed, Speed);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return new Tuple2<>(id, maxspeed);
                    }
                });

        var aggregatedStream = outputStream
                .keyBy(0)  // group by id
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(5)))
                .reduce((v1, v2) -> new Tuple2<>(v1.f0, Math.max(v1.f1, v2.f1)));
        // Set up Elasticsearch properties
        Properties esProps = new Properties();
        esProps.setProperty("cluster.name", "elasticsearch");
        esProps.setProperty("bulk.flush.max.actions", "1");
        esProps.setProperty("bulk.flush.interval.ms", "1000");

        // elasticsearch sink
        List<HttpHost> httpHosts = new ArrayList<>();
        httpHosts.add(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"));

        ElasticsearchSink.Builder<Tuple3<String, Double, Long>> esSinkBuilder = new ElasticsearchSink.Builder<>(
                httpHosts,
                new ElasticsearchSinkFunction<Tuple3<String, Double, Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Tuple3<String, Double, Long> element, RuntimeContext ctx, RequestIndexer indexer) {
                        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();
                        json.put("id", element.f0);
                        json.put("maxspeed", element.f1);
                        json.put("@timestamp", new Date(element.f2).toInstant().toString());
                        IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("test");
                        request.source(json);
                        indexer.add(request);
                    }
                }
        );

        esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxActions(1);
        esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushInterval(1000);

        // create an Elasticsearch sink
        ElasticsearchSink<Tuple3<String, Double, Long>> esSink = esSinkBuilder.build();

        // add the Elasticsearch sink to the output stream
        aggregatedStream.map(new MapFunction<Tuple2<String, Double>, Tuple3<String, Double, Long>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple3<String, Double, Long> map(Tuple2<String, Double> value) throws Exception {
                return Tuple3.of(value.f0, value.f1, System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        }).addSink(esSink);

        aggregatedStream.print();

// execute the program
        env.execute("Flink Data Streaming Example");

    }
    private static long getTimestampFromJson(String event) {
        try {
            JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(event);
            return root.get("timestamp").asLong();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, I would use `KafkaSourceBuilder<String> builder = KafkaSource.xxx`, as you have more explicit control over the Kafka behavior. Second, if you are reading from the latest offset, are you sure you have data arriving in the topic? If not, you want to configure the source to read from its earliest offset.

Comment: @kkrugler Thanks for the response:) 
I tried using KafkaSourceBuilder instead of Kafka consumer, but it didn't work. I was able to see how many records I had received in Flink, but I was unable to see the aggregated output in STDOUT and Elastic Search.